# Possible to set default parameters as variable JS

Tags: javascript

I'm writing my first ever jquery dependant plugin.

My question is can default parameters be variable like so:

```
var s = 400,
    m = 500,
    l = 700,
    xl = 960;

function breakpoints(s = s, m = m, l = l, xl = xl) {
  return {
    s: s,
    m: m,
    l: l,
    xl: xl
  };
};
```

When using `console.log(s, m, l, xl);` inside my initial `breakpoints()` declaration I get the error:

> s is not defined

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: be on the look out for function hoisting.

Comment: So it's just a typo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ES6/ES2015 support default values on arguments, so your code will work so long as the browser supports those standards.

That being said you need to give the outer/inner variables different names, otherwise they won't be available where you attempt to use them. Try this:

```js
var s = 400,
    m = 500,
    l = 700,
    xl = 960;

function breakpoints(_s = s, _m = m, _l = l, _xl = xl) {
  return {
    s: _s,
    m: _m,
    l: _l,
    xl: _xl
  };
};

console.log(breakpoints());
```

Comment: Duplicating variable names in different scopes is a bit of an anti-pattern - I recommend using something like eslint to help flag it up.

Comment: This answers my question @Rory. Will accept when I can. Thank you.

Comment: @DanMad no problem, glad to help

Comment: @Rory I'm agreeing with you and suggesting further steps DanMad might take to help reduce the problem in general. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Ahhh got you :) I'll delete my comment to avoid confusion for any future visitors

Comment: Hi, I'm quite new to Js tag but at 1rst sight the question look like a typo to me. As I can't warp my head around the foo(a=a) as variable visibilty will throw error trying to declare a param like this. Is the fact that it was Js (ES6) is not compatible with all browser that make this question worthy?

Answer (score 1):

You can use default parameters starting from ES6/ES2015. The only issue is that you need to rename your input parameters.

```js
var s = 400,
    m = 500,
    l = 700,
    xl = 960;

function breakpoints(_s = s, _m = m, _l = l, _xl = xl) {
  return {
    s: _s,
    m: _m,
    l: _l,
    xl: _xl
  };
};

console.log(breakpoints());
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var s = 400,
    m = 500,
    l = 700,
    xl = 960;

console.log(breakpoints(s,m,l,xl));

function breakpoints(s, m, l, xl) {
  return {
    s: s,
    m: m,
    l: l,
    xl: xl
  };
};
```